# How to publish calendar using MS Graph and also obtain url of published calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

i created new calendar for user using application permission through MS-Graph (POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars)
Now i am trying to publish the calendar and get the published calendar URL, does anyone know if that can be done through MS-Graph or not? I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything regarding that.

Thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: AFAIK, its not available in Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Being said that you can use Exchange PowerShell or follow the [given post/steps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/how-to-publish-anonymous-calendar-sharing-url-in-exchange-online/ba-p/586924) which will get you the URL of it. Let me know if it helps.